# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactoryin Spring MVC

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to build a simple Spring MVC Web App with the functionality of file uploading.I got following error:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory`

After a quick search,all answers pointed to the missing of dependencies,but it seems not to be true in my case:

I have included the following code in pom.xml:

`<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>`

with `commons.io-2.4.jar` and `commons.fileupload-1.3.1.jar` added into `lib` folder.

One interesting thing I found was that whenever I deleted the code:

```
   <bean id="multipartResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize">
        <value>10000000</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxInMemorySize">
        <value>10000000</value>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

the web app works fine(of course I removed the form for file uploading as well. )

Comment: That class definitely exists in commons-fileupload-1.3.1, so I think you need to double check your deployment to ensure the presence of the jar.

Comment: @SteveC  Thank you very much!!! The problem is the missing jar file in the deployment. I don't quite understand  why the jar file was not automatically included in deployment(I am using intelliJ, I think the jar files in the folder `lib` should be automatically included in artifact) since I have already included them in dependency and they ARE in the lib folder. How could I accept your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you visit the Maven [Central Repository](http://search.maven.org) and enter the search term:

```
fc:org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory
```

then every released artifact available containing that class will be listed.

You will find commons-upload 1.3.1 in that list.

Therefore you need to double check your deployment to ensure that jar is present.

Tip: Use `fc:` to locate jars in Maven Central that contain a specific class.

Answer (score 0):

try to update your jar version, for Example:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

We cann't find versions upper 1.3 on Apache and mvnrepository.com , but you can try this : https://repository.jboss.org/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/

In fact, I encountered the same problem and now working fine with version 2.0 under SpringMVC framework.

Comment: That class is present in commons-fileupload since before 1.0 was released. Updating the version is unlikely to be helpful

Comment: Thanks for response. In fact, the latest version of commons-fileupload is 1.3.1